# If $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ then what space is $f^{\frac{r-p}{r}}$ in?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

If I know that $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, then what can I say about $f^{\frac{r-p}{r}}$? That is, what space does it it live in and why?

The reason I ask is I don't understand how the Generalized Holder Inequality was used in the proof [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Young%27s_Inequality_for_Convolutions#Proof). The relevant section is:
$$ \int \left({\left\vert{ f \left({x - y}\right)}\right\vert^p \cdot \left\vert{g \left({y}\right)}\right\vert^q}\right)^{1/r} \cdot  \left\vert{ f \left({x - y}\right)}\right\vert^{\left({r - p}\right) /r} \cdot \left\vert{ g \left({y}\right)}\right\vert^{ (r-q)/r} ~\mathrm d y
 \le
       \underset{I} {\underbrace{ \left\Vert{ \left({ \left\vert{f \left({x - y}\right)}\right\vert^p \cdot \left\vert{g \left({y}\right)}\right\vert^q }\right)^{1/r} }\right\Vert_r} } \cdot \underset{II}{\underbrace{\left\Vert{\left\vert{f \left({x - y}\right)}\right\vert^{\left({r - p}\right) /r} }\right\Vert_{\textstyle \frac{pr}{r-p} } } } \cdot \underset{III}{\underbrace{\left\Vert{\left\vert{ g \left({y}\right)}\right\vert^{(r-q)/r} }\right\Vert_{\textstyle \frac{qr}{r-q} } } }
$$

I can't see how the particular norms for the terms $I$, $II$ and $III$ were arrived at given only that we know $f \in L^p$ and $g \in L^q$.

Edit: I have also just noticed that in another proof for the same inequality that the numerator and denominator are switched in the norms of $I, II,$ and $III$. The other proof is [here](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2016/math/fa2/serien/ExSheet_1_solution) and is the same up until it states:

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(|f(y)|^{p}|g(x-y)|^{q})^{\frac{1}{r}}|f(y)|^{1 -\frac{p}{r}}|g(x-y)|^{1 -\frac{q}{r}}dy 
\le
||(|f(y)|^{p}|g(x-y)|^{q})^{\frac{1}{r}}||_{L^r}|||f(y)|^{1 -\frac{p}{r}}||_{L^{\frac{r-p}{rp}}}||g(x-y)|^{1 -\frac{q}{r}}||_{L^{\frac{r-q}{rq}}}
$$
So is one of these proofs incorrect or is $L^\frac{pr}{r-p}$ equivalent to $L^\frac{r-p}{rp}$?

Comment: Disregarding signs, $f \in L^p$ means $f^p$ is integrable. So you're looking for the $s$ such that $(f^{\frac{r-p}{r}})^s = f^p$.

Comment: I've just noticed that another proof has the numerator and denominator switched for this step. So is one of them incorrect or is $L^\frac{pr}{r-p}$ equivalent to $L^\frac{r-p}{rp}$?

Comment: It seems to me the second proof is incorrect.

Comment: I agree. It's an easy mistake to make, since the definition of the $L^p$ norm has both $p$ and $1/p$ appearing in it.